# jQuery replace English Number array with Arabic Number array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arabic

I have many spans on my page with this class

```
<span class="price">AED &nbsp;2129</span>
<span class="price">AED &nbsp;4129</span>
```

I want to use jQuery to find all the spans and then replace the AED with the Arabic word of Dirham and also replace the numbers with Arabic numbers.

This is my current code I have been trying for some hours.

```
jQuery('span.price').val(function(i,val) {

    // text
    var en_currency = "AED";
    var ar_currency = "درهم";

    // array
    var f = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', en_currency];
    var r = ['٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩', ar_currency];

    var valArray = val.split(' ');
    jQuery.each(valArray, function(i,v){
       var inF = jQuery.inArray(v, f);
       if(inF !== -1){
         valArray[i] = v.replace(f[inF], r[inF]);
       }
    });
    return valArray.join(' ');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** not **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**, **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** using for getting or setting form fields in case of `span` **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** is needed. Then you can simplify your code with callback in **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)**

```js
// text
var en_currency = "AED";
var ar_currency = "درهم";

// array
var f = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
var r = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];


jQuery('span.price').text(function(i, val) {
  return val.replace(en_currency, ar_currency).replace(/\d/g, function(m) {
    return r[f.indexOf(m)];
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price"> AED 2312 </span>
<span class="price"> AED 1023 </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `text` or `html`. `span` elements don't have value attribute.

```
jQuery('span.price').val(function(i,val) {
//                   ^^^
```

Should be

```
jQuery('span.price').text(function(i,val) {
```

**Demo:**

```js
// text
var en_currency = "AED";
var ar_currency = "درهم";

// array
var f = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
var r = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];


jQuery('span.price').text(function(i, val) {
  val = val.replace(en_currency, ar_currency);
  
  var valArray = val.split('');
  
  jQuery.each(valArray, function(i, v) {
    console.log(i,v);
    var inF = jQuery.inArray(v, f);
    if (inF !== -1) {
      valArray[i] = v.replace(f[inF], r[inF]);
    }
  });
  return valArray.join('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price">AED &nbsp;2129</span>
<span class="price">AED &nbsp;4129</span>
```

Comment: Just curious, but would Javascript also require `unescape` on the arabic characters as they look unicode? Or is that safety on my part?

Comment: I upvoted your answer, it works and is concise, I was just wondering (I am not familiar with arabic characters).

Comment: I upvoted for the effort but the answer I think is cleaner than this. Thanks though my friend!

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Yeah, I agree, I've also upvoted it :)